# Performance reduce when draw more object with OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to code an FPS with OpenGL and C++, and the first object (a cube with texture) is normal when I move the viewpoint, but when I try to draw a static crosshair, the program start to lag. Here is the main loop pseudo code:

```
while (running) {
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertices.size(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    textureLoad("sample.png");
    enableAttribute();

    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0), 600 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraLook, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, crossVertices.size(), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    textureLoad("crosshair.png");
    enableAttribute();

    proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0), 600 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));

    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 0, 2), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    app.display();
}
```

I guess the glBufferData is the cause. So is there a different way make it faster even with mutiple object?

Comment: 1) *Don't* post pseudo code, post a [mcve]. 2) Make sure that all performance measurements you do are done with optimized builds, *not* with unoptimized debug builds. 3) Of course doing more slows down things - what did you expect? A speedup?

Comment: Outside loop call bufferdata method once with last parameter set to null. Then in loop call glbuffersubdata.

Comment: Do you load the images again in every frame (`textureLoad("sample.png");`)?

Comment: Yes i did. So that is the main cause?

Comment: @BhBh Create and load data to the OpenGL texture and buffer objects before the main loop and use them in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some OpenGL function calls that do not fit well within the main-loop. glBufferData is one of them. Its purpose is to upload to the GPU some buffer of data. That's a costly operation. Once the buffer of data is uploaded, you can re-use on the GPU multiple times.

So, you should create and fill up the new buffer outside your main loop: [glGenBuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml), [glBindBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml), [glBufferData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml).

Then, inside your main loop when you are ready to ready your cube, you just have to re-bind it using [glBindBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml). This should greatly improve your application's performance.